# Support vector regression: ValueError: Found array with dim 3. StandardScaler expected <= 2

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, scale

I'm trying to perform a supporting vector regression on my datasets, however I have run into a problem when trying to standard scale my datasets.

Originally I was facing an issue of "ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead".

I tried to change the shape of my datasets, but I'm now facing an issue ValueError: Found array with dim 3. StandardScaler expected <= 2.

Could anyone please help me out how can I proceed to eliminate this issue?

Below is what I have done:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dataset=pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Sammy\OneDrive - International Campus, Zhejiang University\Desktop\Data\BAYC Data.xlsx')
print(dataset)
dataset.columns
x=dataset.iloc[:,1].values
y=dataset.iloc[:,2].values
x=dataset.iloc[:,0].to_frame()
x=np.expand_dims(x, axis = -1)
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
st_x=StandardScaler()
st_y=StandardScaler()
X=st_x.fit_transform(x)
Y=st_y.fit_transform(y)
```

And this is the error I'm receiving:

> ```
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
> ~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_11140\1840045772.py in <module>
> ----> 1 X=st_x.fit_transform(x)
>       2 Y=st_y.fit_transform(y)
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
>     850         if y is None:
>     851             # fit method of arity 1 (unsupervised transformation)
> --> 852             return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
>     853         else:
>     854             # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_data.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
>     804         # Reset internal state before fitting
>     805         self._reset()
> --> 806         return self.partial_fit(X, y, sample_weight)
>     807 
>     808     def partial_fit(self, X, y=None, sample_weight=None):
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_data.py in partial_fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
>     839         """
>     840         first_call = not hasattr(self, "n_samples_seen_")
> --> 841         X = self._validate_data(
>     842             X,
>     843             accept_sparse=("csr", "csc"),
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in _validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, **check_params)
>     564             raise ValueError("Validation should be done on X, y or both.")
>     565         elif not no_val_X and no_val_y:
> --> 566             X = check_array(X, **check_params)
>     567             out = X
>     568         elif no_val_X and not no_val_y:
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator)
>     792                 ) from e
>     793         if not allow_nd and array.ndim >= 3:
> --> 794             raise ValueError(
>     795                 "Found array with dim %d. %s expected <= 2."
>     796                 % (array.ndim, estimator_name)
>
> ValueError: Found array with dim 3. StandardScaler expected <= 2.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to "push" 3d array to the function that need 2d array.

I would recommend delete rows 9 and 10, and in rows 7 and 8 edit the values in [], so the dataset.iloc will give you 2d array :)